Heroku Stuck on Installing node modules
as the title states i have created a nodejs project, this is my first "clean deploy" where i just import from github and then add the env and buildpack for nodejs then deploy from the latest build,
Heres the log:
-----> Building on the Heroku-24 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=development
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):   20.15.0
       engines.npm (package.json):    10.9.0
       
       Resolving node version 20.15.0...
       Downloading and installing node 20.15.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 10.9.0 (replacing 10.7.0)...
       npm 10.9.0 installed
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules

heres my package.json
{
  "name": "xyz-crm-business-ai",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Business AI Training Backend",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "echo 'No build required'",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "1.4.5-lts.1",
    "openai": "^4.20.1",
    "puppeteer": "^21.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}

and finally heres my env
SUPABASE_URL=*************
SUPABASE_KEY=*************
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=*************
DEV_FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:5173
FRONTEND_URL=*************


# Server Configuration
PORT=3000
NODE_ENV=development
# File Upload Configuration
MAX_FILE_SIZE=10485760 # 10MB in bytes
MAX_FILES=10

# Chrome configuration
CHROME_PATH=/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome  # For Mac
# CHROME_PATH=C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe  # For Windows
# CHROME_PATH=/usr/bin/google-chrome  # For Linux
PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true  # Optional: Use system Chrome
CHROME_BIN=/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

i have tried deleting all the node modules, and package lock, and re-pushing, and then another build ends up happening waiting for the previous to finish, i have deleted app and tried again as well
Thanks in advance

did you find a resolution to this? we are running into the same thing.

yeah issue with puppeeter, if you dont have puppeeter then its another one of the libraries is cauing that issue

The issue ended up being with puppeeter, heroku has an issue with it, to fix it we have to add a flag to the build.
When Puppeteer is installed, it triggers a download of a large file such as Chrome. Depending on the network, this can cause a build to timeout. We've found that users no longer see timeouts after adding a PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD config var and setting it to true. This skips the Chrome download and has improved build time.

It works for me! +1.

My issue is with date-fns 2.9.0 not installing. I went to Heroku and tried to npm install manually and it sits there until sometimes timing out after a long period of time.
Then sometimes it says
The authenticity of host 'http://github.com (140.82.113.3)' can't be established.acted to /app/server/node_modules/.staging/date-fns-74841dec (4779ms)
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names

I searched on Github here and the SHA256 data does match ok. So I wonder if this is a Heroku issue where known_hosts needs an additional entry?
I can't find the known_hosts on my dyno and not confident it would stick around even if I found it.
This could be a situation where npm install is going to github instead of a regular npm repository. I'm new and not sure. But I am loading a specific tag of a github repository right after date-fns which may be the real issue.
UPDATE: It may not be date-fns at all...but a github repository where I'm trying to install a specific tag. Still, it is balking at github fingerprints not being known.
UPDATE 2: This may be related to the upgrade November 6, security patches, etc. Maybe not. But maybe. We pushed within the last 2 weeks prior to Nov 6 and did not have issues. https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/3052
